# Instance on Django form not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to do the second part of the sign up process in which the person (in portuguese Pessoa) would give some extra info about himself and also would register some info about the car he owns (checked by a checkbox in the template called 'tem_carro', in english would be 'has_car').
In this step the person would already have a username and password as well as some basic info such as name, that are mandatory and would fill the non mandatory info.

The problem that the `instance=pessoa` (which supposedly gets the mandatory info from that person) is not working and I thus I can't validade the form.

In views.py:

```
def continuar_cadastro(request):
    pessoa = request.user.pessoa # this is working
    # and changing the above line to pessoa = Pessoa.objects.get(id = 1) for exemple doesn't solve either the validation problem
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pessoaForm = CadastroPessoaForm(request.POST, instance=pessoa)  # the form isn't getting the pessoa's info (primeiro_nome and sobrenome)
        if pessoaForm.is_valid():   # I can't get past here!
            try:
                request.POST['tem_carro']
                carro = Carro(motorista=pessoa)
                carroForm = CadastroCarroForm(request.POST, instance=carro)
                if carroForm.is_valid():
                    carroForm.save()
                    pessoaForm.save()
                else:
                    print(carroForm)
                    return HttpResponse("<script>alert('Form do carro inválido.');javascript:history.back();</script>")
            except:
                pessoaForm.save()
        else:
            print(pessoaForm)
            return HttpResponse("<script>alert('Form de informações pessoais inválido.');javascript:history.back();</script>")
    return render_to_response('continuar_cadastro.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In forms.py:

```
class CadastroPessoaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa
        exclude =('usuario', 'nome_completo')
```

In models.py:

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name= 'pessoa')
    primeiro_nome = models.CharField("Primeiro nome", max_length= 64)
    sobrenome = models.CharField("Sobrenome", max_length=64)
    celular = models.CharField("Calular", max_length= 16, null=True, blank=True)
    residencial = models.CharField("Residencial", max_length=16, null=True, blank=True)
```

Thank you!

Edit 1: 
The error I am getting when validating the form is this (I printed the form):

```
<tr><th><label for="id_primeiro_nome">Primeiro nome:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_primeiro_nome" maxlength="64" name="primeiro_nome" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_sobrenome">Sobrenome:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_sobrenome" maxlength="64" name="sobrenome" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_celular">Calular:</label></th><td><input id="id_celular" maxlength="16" name="celular" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_residencial">Residencial:</label></th><td><input id="id_residencial" maxlength="16" name="residencial" type="text" value="khsdjgf" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view is not creating the form for get requests - how are you rendering the initial form?

If the form is not valid, print `pessoaForm.errors` to see what the problem is. Print `request.POST` to make sure the expected data is there. It looks like there's a problem with the sobernome field, so check that especially closely.

Comment: Actually I took that in account. When I get `request.user.pessoa` I am actually calling the `Pessoa` object related to that `User`. I can do that by using the `related_name= 'pessoa'` attribute in the class `Pessoa`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is the approach you're using to implememt an **"user profile"**. See [Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). You already are half way.

When you have configured the user profile correctly then you can associate the form to your profile class -- **Pessoa** in this case --.

On the other hand, you are excluding `usuario` and `nome_completo` but the last is not a field of `Pessoa` class.

Also, your `Pessoa` class has fields which porpuse are the same of some `User` model fields for instance: `primeiro_nome`.

Recommendation:

1. Visite the link I posted.
2. Review you design, maybe  you don't want to define the field `primeiro_nome` in the `Pessoa` class.
3. Check that the data in `request.user.pessoa` is what your're expecting for. Meaning that  `primeiro_nome` and `sobrenome` fields have some data.

Finally in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998206/django-form-bind-data-after-initialization) -- at last comment -- you can see this OP was struggling with something like your problem.

He said: *For the record I also tried `user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user, prefix='user')`: No error but that **always returns an empty form**.*

Maybe you can try to load your form the way this answer propossed.